# Laravel change path to controllers, models and views at runtime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Would it be possible to change specific paths like path to controllers, models and views folders inside:

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    // Change paths to controllers, models and views
});
```

if so, how could I achieve that? Could I achieve this with `Config::set()`?

My application runs multiple clients that all need different folders for mvc...

Note: I can't touch the config files themselves.

Comment: You could use `ClassLoader` to handle class loading paths and `View::addLocation` for view paths, but without a more clear structure of your application it's hard to give advice. Please provide more details.

Comment: Thank you! :) I've looked at ClassLoader and noticed it has a function addDirectories which is perfect for me, with it I can include models and controllers. The View::addLocation function is also what I was looking for. Thanks again!